# Installing Admissions Connect

Tags: npsp, education-data-architecture

I have tried to install Admissions Connect package in dev org, EDA trial org using the link below:
https://install.salesforce.org/products/admissions-connect/latest/install

But before installing it asks to run a validation process to check the compatibility of the existing org. It always give the below error:

> Admissions Connect licenses have not yet been provisioned to this
> Salesforce org. Contact your Salesforce Account Executive to be sure
> you have the correct licenses set up in your org.

I read the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sfdo.ac_prereq.htm&type=5), I thought there might be some permission set that needs to be assigned to the user, but I don't see anything like that anywhere. Do anyone of you aware of what needs to be done?

The documentation says:

> To use Admissions Connect, you need an Enterprise, Unlimited, or
> Developer Edition org with:
>
> - Lightning Experience enabled
> - Service Cloud Lightning Console enabled
> - Full access to Contact, Account, and other standard objects

Comment: The best resource for EDA support is the [Education Hub](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000001ogNCAQ?tab=discussion&_ga=2.44928740.132613547.1664036974-2041321918.1664036974&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC) on Trailblazer.

Comment: Admissions Connect is a separate license from EDA. Have you purchased licenses for Admissions Connect?

Comment: @DavidReed I am trying to install this package in a dev org. Do I need to purchase it? The documentation clearly says "To use Admissions Connect, you need an Enterprise, Unlimited, or Developer Edition org....."

Comment: @DavidReed I also tried with a trial EDA org, the one with 30 days. That is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admissions Connect is a paid, licensed product. You must purchase licenses for Admissions Connect before you can install it in your org.

Note that the Admissions Connect license is distinct from EDA (Education Data Architecture), which is free and open source.

*Disclosure: I work for Salesforce and support the Education Cloud teams, but am not on the Admissions Connect team*.

Comment: That's nice to know.